# The bullets in my <ul> items are all right-aligned

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to add something to a webpage with an unordered list attribute, but for some reason the first one in the list is acting strangely. For some reason, it puts the disc after the sentence instead of before it, and not just right after, but totally at the right of the page; the following in-line styles do work like they should though.

Strangely enough, in Dreamweaver it looks correct, and if I try it in an online editor (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists4) it just shows up good too, but if I upload it to the page then I it starts acting strangely.

```
<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
  <li>de problemen die u heeft</li>
  <li>wat u graag ziet wat er verandert</li>
  <li>of u andere therapieën, trainingen en/of activiteiten u volgt</li>
  <li>of u medicijnen krijgt, en zo ja welke</li>
  <li>of u tijdens uw behandeling kunt en wilt werken</li>
  <li>verslaglegging  evaluatie.</li>
</ul>
```

this is the list. I added the style to it as I thought that was the problem, but then I noticed that it was just showing up behind the first sentence.

A bit further into my code, I have another list, and that just doesn't even show up as a list.

```
<ul>
<li>Intakegesprek-  gratis*</li>
<li>Stress  counseling - 1 uur - € 45,00</li>
<li>Combinatie  stress-counseling / ontspanningsmassage 1,5 uur - € 65,00</li>
</ul>
```

You guys have any ideas on what might be wrong?

edit: here is the css code:

```
/* CSS Document */
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #fffbff;
    color: #6F6F00;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

div, p, ul, h2, h3, h4, {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#prijs{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #fffbff;
    color: #6F6F00;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

#welcome h2{
    width: 470px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url(../images/h_welcome.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-bottom: #d1cfd1 1px solid;
    background-image: url(../images/h_welcome.gif);
}

#hotstone {
    width:485;
    height:275;
}

.mailto2 {
    color:#6F6F00; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.mailto2 A:link {text-decoration: none}
.mailto2 A:visited {text-decoration: none}
.mailto2 A:active {text-decoration: none}
.mailto2 A:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

a:link {text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
font-family:Arial;
line-height:14px;
color: #6F6F00}
A:visited {text-decoration: none}
A:active {text-decoration: none}
A:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Comment: You need to post your CSS in your question because what you showed us doesn't do what you describe.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your code you change the style for all `ul` elements?

Comment: I suspect there is additional CSS which you haven't provided affecting the list.

Comment: sorry guys, i added the css

Comment: Still not enough code: http://jsfiddle.net/pq2sx5h0/

Comment: None of the css you posted has to do with the UL's.

Comment: that is why i am asking here, cause that was the first place i looked and i have no idea where the problem lies or why it is only happening to the first in line not the rest...

Comment: Well the reset of the `ul` does but other than that it's pretty unhelpful.

Comment: @FGOD I can only suggest you make a demo in JSFiddle that **actually demonstrates the problem**...without it we can't help.

Comment: @j08691 i know, that is why i asked here cause everywhere i try this code i works perfectly and for some reason it doesn't on the page and only for the first in the list it is acting strange not the rest...

Comment: You do have the `px` missing from the `#hotstone` CSS so that may be an issue but it seems unlikely.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/FGOD/26a4h5vh/

Comment: this is the full code and css of the page, and still it acts normally on test... but not on the webpage...

Comment: hmmm just thinking out loud... the page is loaded in a pan, could it be that the page where the pan is loaded could mess this up?

Comment: You have a `ul` inside of a paragraph...that's invalid HTML..so you will get rendering issues, In fact the whole structure is pretty poor. - https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/optimizing-debugging-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul style="list-style-position:inside;list-style-type:disc;">
  <li>de problemen die u heeft</li>
  <li>wat u graag ziet wat er verandert</li>
  <li>of u andere therapieën, trainingen en/of activiteiten u volgt</li>
  <li>of u medicijnen krijgt, en zo ja welke</li>
  <li>of u tijdens uw behandeling kunt en wilt werken</li>
  <li>verslaglegging  evaluatie.</li>
</ul>
```

If still doesn't work, try to put the same styles for LI elements.

Comment: i don't know why but it worked! thanks a lot... although i still wonder why it was screwed up...

Comment: I think as someone mentioned before, you can have some additional styles.. inspect element in [dev-tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#devtools-window)